# About Collatz Conjecture

Tags: soft-question, collatz-conjecture

Please explain to me, what do Terence Tao and other mathematicians who write books about the Collatz Conjecture, what do they want to do in general? Do they want to prove this hypothesis, or disprove it?

**What can we generally conclude from these books?
what are the mathematical predictions about this problem ,what is it in general?**

Comment: They contain what we currently know about Collatz conjecture. For example, Steiner (1977) proved that there is no 1-cycle other than the trivial (1;2); Simons & de Weger (2003) extended this proof up to 68-cycles: there is no k-cycle up to k = 68. Knowledge of this sort makes finding counter-examples easier.

Comment: I don't know that there is a clear consensus on the Collatz conjecture.  There are some heuristics which make it plausible, but I don't think anyone would be too terribly shocked by some big counterexample.  At the moment, all we can do is to search for counterexamples, try to prove what we can, and make predictions based on it which we can then test.

Comment: @lulu incredible..You say that, maybe there is a counterexample??

Comment: Sure, why not?  I don't see how anyone could claim intuition over a problem like this, and all the trials we conduct are still on very, very small numbers (in the vast scheme of things).  Still, if you asked me to guess I'd say the conjecture is probably true.  But it's just a guess and a big counterexample would not shock me.

Comment: @lulu I appreciate you giving me an answer...

Comment: @Student As long as the Collatz problem is open we cannot rule out a counter-example. If we actually knew there isn't one, we would know that the Collatz-conjecture is true. But we do not know it yet.

Comment: @Peter Answering the question made me happy..thanks.

Comment: @Peter What is your own opinion? lulu already said. Can you ask?.

Comment: @Student I agree lulu , I also tend to believe that it is true. But to be honest, I would find a counterexample (or just a disprove) more interesting although a proof would be truely sensational.

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much.

Comment: Although they may not have solved the problem in question, they generally want to share their learnings and insights, what they conjecture might be approaches to tackle the problem, and perhaps some of the reasons why they believe the problem is difficult.

Comment: @lulu I think most who have studied the problem in any depth would be surprised by any counterexample. The reason is... there can not be some **isolated** counterexample. The smallest counterexample would be the base of a tree which branches at the same rate as the tree known to branch from 1 and its predecessors must occupy the ranges of numbers occupied by the trivial tree.  Furthermore, if it did not terminate in a loop it would also have infinitely many successors which would again have to occupy the same ranges of numbers, every odd successor also having infinitely many other predecessors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [The Ultimate Challenge: the 3x+1 Problem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849409) by Jeffrey Lagarias (which is a collection of papers by various writers).  There are papers and chapters in books by others.

But generally, the *books* on the Collatz conjecture seem to be the self-published writings of cranks.

Comment: What is   crank?? Ohh sorry English is not my native language..

Comment: An interesting look at cranks is here: https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Cranks-Spectrum-Underwood-Dudley/dp/0883855070/

Comment: Finally...,what is your personal thought about this conjecture? can I ask??